# What does << operator does with ruby methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I know `<<` operator is used for `appending an object to a collection` as well as `string`.

What does the `<<` operator does in the following code snippets?

```
 module TriangleBox
    def available_width
      height + 25
    end
  end

  Prawn::Text::Box.extensions << TriangleBox
```

I found it in the Prawn gem [examples](https://github.com/sandal/prawn/blob/stable/manual/text/text_box_extensions.rb) page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't think of it as an operator.  Think of it as a method that has some syntactic sugar to make it look like an operator.

The code

```
Prawn::Text::Box.extensions << TriangleBox
```

is actually calling

```
Prawn::Text::Box.extensions.<<(TriangleBox)
```

What is this method doing?  In short, there's no way to tell without reading the documentation for Prawn (though we can make a guess that this is overriding the default available_width method by adding a module that it extends).  You can define the << method to do whatever you want.

```
class Silly
  def <<(anything)
    puts "I hate chicken"
  end
end

a = Silly.new
a << 73
=> I hate chicken
```

Answer (score 1):

You said it yourself: it's "appending an object to a collection". In this case, the object is the module `TriangleBox` and the collection is `Prawn::Text::Box.extensions`, which appears to be an `Array`.

Answer (score 1):

It's appending an item to a collection.

Exactly how it's doing that, though, is hidden from you.  It may be that `Prawn::Text::Box.extensions` just returns a regular Array, in which case it's the default behaviour.  But it could also be that it's some other class, and the Prawn guys have written a custom `<<` operator to do whatever work is required to install an extension.

Unfortunately, there's no easy way to tell short of digging through the source, figuring out what the class of `Prawn::Text::Box.extensions` is, and then if it has a custom `<<` function defined.  Fortunately, it's all open source on github...

Hope that helps (and good luck, if you go digging)!